# How can I zip iterators into an (iterator[1:],iterator[0]) type structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, zip, python-itertools

For example:

```
d=iter([iter(range(3)),iter(range(4)),iter(range(5))])
L1z=zip(d,map(lambda x: next(x),d))
for ran,first in L1z:
    for i in ran:
        print(first,i)
```

This code printed out:

```
0 0    
0 1    
0 2
```

But I was expecting it to print out:

```
0 1    
0 2    
0 1    
0 2    
0 3    
0 1    
0 2    
0 3    
0 4
```

Why is this wrong/ how can I do this right and quickly?

Comment: This works if d is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d=iter([iter(range(3)),iter(range(4)),iter(range(5))])
L1z=((x,next(x)) for x in d)
```

The problem I was originally having was that map evaluates each generator in d thus deleting the entire generator.

This solution wraps d inside another generator.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a convoluted approach, I'll offer a more simplistic one. First, create `d` with a simple generator comprehension:

```
d= (range(1, i) for i in [3, 4, 5])
```

Then, with the help of `zip_longest` and `chain.from_iterable` create a `zip` for every range with an empty list so the `fillvalue` of `0` can be applied to it:

```
for i in from_it(izip([],i, fillvalue=0) for i in d):
    print(*i)
```

Rename a few things to make this a bit more compact:

```
from_it = chain.from_iterable    
izip = zip_longest
```

and you end up with:

```
for i in from_it(izip([],i, fillvalue=0) for i in d):
    print(*i)
```

which yields:

```
0 1
0 2
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
```